# testing if something is null in visualforce, NOT(ISNULL())) vs. != null

Tags: visualforce, validation

Is there a difference between the two statements?

`{!NOT(ISNULL(variable))}` and `{!variable != null}`

What is the appropriate way to check if something is null?

EDIT:  What if it's a SF checkbox?  Does `!= null` validate if its unchecked or does this not apply here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do either way but I prefer `{!variable != null}`.

One thing that might often be a better idea though is to do the checks in the controller so that less of the logic is in the VF page.

EDIT:  SObject booleans will always be true/false.  It won't be null.

Comment: Thanks! I added an edit - as it doesn't seem to apply to checkboxes.  Could you address? :)

Comment: @JacobRaccuia html checkboxes or Visualforce checkboxes?

Comment: checkboxes from a salesforce object - is the box checked?

Comment: Checkboxes on a Salesforce object can never be null. They have two values, true or false.

Comment: However, all apex variables, even booleans can have a null value. It really depends then on whether or not your are binding to an sObject or your own boolean property on your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Either syntax works, both are exactly the same.

Comment: True, it's really just a matter of whether you're more used to Excel-style formula syntax or programmer-ish syntax. However, ISNULL() is deprecated - use ISBLANK() instead.

Comment: If you're checking in the controller you may also use the String method isNotBlank().  However, in VF I don't believe there is an ISNOTBLANK() function, just ISBLANK().